# Porting VSTO Outlook Add-In to Mobile Device

Tags: android, ios, mobile, vsto, outlook-addin

We recently created a VSTO Add-In for Outlook 2016 using the Outlook 2016 Office Project Type in Visual Studio 2017 and was recently asked if it's possible to port our Outlook Add-In to mobile devices (IOS/Android).

We've done some research on whether this is possible, however not sure if this can be done, at least easily from reading this article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/outlook-mobile-addins

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft Outlook app on mobile platforms is doesn't support VSTO add-ins. If you would like to bring some functionality into mobile apps you may consider to look at Office.js Add-ins. The resource you have provided talks exactly about this type of add-ins. You may get an idea if you want to invest into development of Office.js add-in by reading ... [How are Office Add-ins different from COM and VSTO add-ins?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins#how-are-office-add-ins-different-from-com-and-vsto-add-ins)